# How to set table cell border to dashed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to be able to create and format a table cell in a document (*not* a spreadsheet) using a Google App Script, and everything is working except I can't figure out how to set the border to dashed.  This needs to have the same effect as if the "Border Dash" was selected from the tools and a non-solid border was selected.  I have looked at the Table object, the TableCell Object, at the Attributes, and I can't find anything regarding how to set the dashing, only color and width.

Comment: I see nothing about it in the doc, but a workaround could be possible. You say you need to create a table cell in a document but could there already be a dotted table here that you could duplicate programatically?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Unfortunately no, although we are already using this as a workaround to copy/paste from another document (for manual use) but we are trying to automate and save time as there are a lot of files being migrated with stuff Google does not properly format in a copy/paste or upload.

Comment: could you have a "template" document with a dotter table that you could duplicate and fill or is it the same issue?